# QGIS Viewer, QGIS read only?

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to create a read-only project in QGIS? Or is there any viewer software available for QGIS project file? What I am after is a read-only project that shows and keep labels and rendering.

Comment: Use QGIS server http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial and some WMS client (OpenLayers, Leaflet).

Answer (score 4):

One of the possibilities you've is to customize the QGIS interface in order to hide the tools you don't want any one see. Check this http://linfiniti.com/2011/07/customizing-the-qgis-ui/

Comment: Customization isn't really usable for this purpose because As far as I can see, it isn't possible to customize all the "toggle editing" buttons, at least not in QGis 2.8.2: It's true that it is possible to remove them from the main menu and from the digitizing tool bar but not from the context menu of a layer or from the tool bar in an attribute table.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your file system's tools: put the project file and data in a directory that is read only for your users